# How do I sql query for records containing an ampersand in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database of customer names and am looking to select only the names that contain an ampersand somewhere in them.  I have concatenated the first and last name together and just need to return any records that contain an ampersand.

I've tried using `contains` and `like %&%` but neither of those is working because MS access seems to see the ampersand as a variable of some sort?

Here's the code that gives me the lsit of full name, as well as a unique identifier I can use to find the record in the original database.

```
SELECT [BillTo_FirstName] & " " & [BillTo_LastName] AS FullName, 
June_ampersand.MerchantReferenceNumber
FROM June_ampersand
;
```

Comment: Please include the attempted `LIKE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access uses different wildcards for LIKE operator - try `LIKE '*&*'` condition

Comment: When I do that I get a pop up asking me to put in parameter values for FullName

Comment: Can you post the query you are running?

Comment: Technically, this is only true if running MS Access via the GUI (.EXE). If connecting via ODBC like in application layer languages (Java, R, VBA, etc.), the `%` wildcard operator works. See [docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-wildcards-in-queries-and-parameters-in-access-ec057a45-78b1-4d16-8c20-242cde582e0b) pages. Use `ALIKE` (ANSI-Like) for consistency to always use `%` in any mode of MS Access.

Comment: with the attempted like expression: SELECT [BillTo_FirstName] & " " & [BillTo_LastName] AS FullName, June_ampersand.MerchantReferenceNumber
FROM June_ampersand
WHERE FullName LIKE '*&*';

Comment: FullName synonym is not visible in where clause, you have two options to fix this: ```SELECT * FROM (SELECT [BillTo_FirstName] & " " & [BillTo_LastName] AS FullName, June_ampersand.MerchantReferenceNumber FROM June_ampersand) WHERE FullName LIKE '*&*' ``` or ```SELECT [BillTo_FirstName] & " " & [BillTo_LastName] AS FullName, June_ampersand.MerchantReferenceNumber FROM June_ampersand WHERE BillTo_FirstName LIKE '*&*' OR BillTo_LastName LIKE '*&*'```